PostgreSql definition Primary Key is not working
I am creating a table in Postgresql, this DDL is the result of a script that I am making to compare bancos.
CREATE TABLE projeto_modelo.exemplo_fk1 
(
    id SERIAL NOT NULL,
    nome varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    criado_em timestamp NOT NULL,
    id_exmp_fk2 int4 NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT exemplo_fk1_id_exmp_fk2_fkey 
        FOREIGN KEY (id_exmp_fk2) 
        REFERENCES projeto_modelo.exemplo_fk2(id),
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

The problem is when a check in DBeaver the specifications of my table. DBeaver recommends:
CREATE TABLE projeto_modelo.exemplo_fk1 
(
    id serial4 NOT NULL,
    nome varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    criado_em timestamp NOT NULL,
    id_exmp_fk2 int4 NOT NULL
);

And when I check constraints nothing appears.
I expected an explanation for this.

Two suggestions: 1) use bigint for all automatically generated primary keys 2) use GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY instead of serial.

I solved this problem in the DBeaver graphical interface, I just updated the table and when I went to check again, the two constraints created were there.

FYI, both those constraints can be declared directly on the columns id for the PK and  id_exmp_fk2 for the FK.
